# scrollviewer to scroll to textbox position

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, scrollview, silverlight-toolkit

How I can get behavior of form in windows Phone like `Settings >> Mobile Network >> EditAPN`.
In this page it have many textboxes in scrollviewer. When user taps on any textbox and its get focus then the page scrolls up and header remains constant and SIP keyboard shown. And when user lost the focus from this text box then page comes to its normal state and SIP keyboard hides and header remains unchanged. I want to achieve this behavior. I placed some textboxes in scrollviewer and on each textbox got focus event I am doing this.

```
this.Scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(this.txtbox1.ActualHeight); 
this.Scroller.UpdateLayout();
```

But Its not working for me. Any help will be appreciates

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to reset default behavior to move page up when SIP is visible with code:

```
(App.Current as App).RootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
```

on `TextBox_Focus` event. Than collapse header and scroll manually what you need.

Comment: I didnot get you more clearly. As I know this line will prevent page render transformation. Not Scroll To That Point. Can You Please express more. If I am mistaken

Comment: By default all page is moved up and header become out of the page. If you need to prevent this, reset render transform and scroll content manually

Comment: OK. I got the point to stop the transformation. but how i can scroll the content manually ??

Comment: with `ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset_from_top)` you mentioned above