# Windows Phone - Page sometimes not automatically scrolling when keyboard comes up

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer, on-screen-keyboard

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7.1 app and I have a ScrollViewer with an ItemsControl inside it, where each item in the ItemsControl contains two TextBoxes.  When the user taps a TextBox on the lower half of the screen to enter a value, the screen usually scrolls up so that the on-screen keyboard doesn't cover up the focused TextBox.  However, in my app this only happens about 50% of the time.  The other 50%, the keyboard still comes up but the screen doesn't scroll up and the focused TextBox gets covered by the on-screen keyboard.

Since it doesn't always happen and I can't reliably make the problem happen or prevent it, I'm guessing that there's some kind of race condition occurring between 2 threads involving updating the layout or something.  Just a guess.

Is there a method I should be calling in the TextBoxes' GotFocus events to ensure that the auto-scrolling when focusing on a TextBox will work?  Maybe something similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795865/scrolling-is-disabled-limited-when-keyboard-is-popped-up-in-windows-phone-7-5)'s answer?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the issue came from something I did in the TextBox_GotFocus event handler: I was changing the opacity of the Application Bar to 1.0 when the keyboard came up and I changed the opacity back to its old value (~0.7) in the TextBox_LostFocus event handler.  Removing the `ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;` line fixed the problem.  However, it doesn't solve the real problem introduced by this question, which seems to be a multi-threading problem.